# Photoshop - Is there a keyboard shortcut for creating a new frame?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, cs6, cs5

In Adobe Photoshop CS5.5 / CS6, is there a keyboard shortcut to make a new frame using the animation window and timeline?

I make a lot of gif animations and would like to reduce mouse movement for productivity.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. But, you can make a hotkey for it.

From top menu: `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts..` <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+K</kbd>

Just select `Palette menus` from the drop down list and then `Animations`. Once you've given a hotkey press `Accept`.
[image]

( Make sure to listen to photoshop when it warns you if the inserted hotkey combination would override any existing ones. You can try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to make sure that it doesn't happen. )

Comment: Yes! woo hoo! This is like Dreamweaver I was looking for this menu before; I was looking for Macros though! Thank you so much. Repped and marked.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Oh, and FYI if you give hotkey like this, it will start showing that hotkey in the menu where the function can be found. ( Incase you keep forgetting what you set.. or something. )

Answer (score -2):

[Further list of shortcuts](http://creativealive.com/adobe-photoshop-cs5-keyboard-shortcuts-mac-windows/), some of them are very interesting.

[image]